# C#: Cannot figure out how to use resource file in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, embedded-resource

I need to create a resource file for my projects to hold a couple of messages as strings and have tried to figure out how they work.

I've created a new resource file in "*project -> properties -> resources*" and created an entry with:

`Name = fooBar` and `Value = barFoo`

I can now see Resources.resx in SolutionExplorer under my project name ConsoleApplication2

This is where I've come to a stop, I can't find sufficient information on how to use my string in the project. I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(Something.Something.fooBar)
```

What namespaces have to start at the beginning?
How do I access the string within my project?

I'm using **VS2013 Ultimate** if that's of any importance

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
Properties.Resources.fooBar
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Properties` folder under your project works like a namespace, so you need to add a using or reference it as follows:

```
<project namespace>.Properties.Resources
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the namespace from Resources1.Designer.cs file. Add this namespace reference in your file with using statement.
Then you can directly use .fooBar to get the value.